# Unmet dependencies due to slightly too new package installed

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dependencies

When I tried to `apt-get upgrade` (yes, I did an update first), I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-samba : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u2) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is installed
                Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u2) but 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So the culprit appears to be `libwbclient0` which is required in subversion `deb9u2` but apparently installed in `deb9u3`. When I try to run `--fix-broken` as suggested by `apt-get` the remove scripts seem to crash because of a missing package `maketrans` and later `ConfigParser`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-samba
Suggested packages:
  python-gpgme
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-samba
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,364 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 567338 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 32, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/namespace.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/pydist.py", line 27, in <module>
    from string import maketrans
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 32, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/namespace.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/pydist.py", line 27, in <module>
    from string import maketrans
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am on debian stretch 9.4 with the kernel:
`Linux 3.10-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.7-1`

After my own attempts failed and I couldn't find anything online how to fix this, I asked `aptitude` and `synaptic` to give it a go. Both tried something but also failed.

I don't even need samba, so getting rid of it would be fine, but `apt` doesn't want to remove anything before I don't fix the broken package:

```
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
```

is a Python 3 error, which results from trying to import `maketrans` as you would do in Python 2 code. This means that `/usr/bin/python` in your system is a Python 3 interpreter; this breaks Debian derivatives.

To fix this, assuming `python2.7` is still installed, you need to fix the `/usr/bin/python` symlink so it points at `/usr/bin/python2.7`:

```
sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```